# Get javafx TableColumn from corresponding column-header Node

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

I'm replacing the javafx context menus of a table's columns. The context menu will give the user access to excel like filtering of the table view. 
Everything is working, but i now wan't to open the context menu on any mouse click event on the column header. Not just the standard right click.

The problem hereby is, that you can only get the header node by a lookupAll() inside the parent tableview.
Due to the fact, that a lookup is only possible after the table view has been rendered, i call this method with a Platform.runLater(..).

TableView Class:

```
private void setHeaderNodesEventHandler() {
    int i = 0;
    for (final Node headerNode : lookupAll(".column-header")) {
        ((AbstractFilterableTableColumn<E, ?>) getColumns().get(i)).setHeaderNodeEventHandler(headerNode);
        i++;
    }
}
```

TableColumn Class:

```
public void setHeaderNodeEventHandler(final Node headerNode) {
    headerNode.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(final MouseEvent e) {
            contextMenu.show(headerNode, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
        }
    });
}
```

Problem here is, that i have to believe, that the order of the found headerNodes is the same as the columns. And i really don't need something bad happen here.

I would rather have something like that (see below), which is not possible, because i'm not able to cast from Parent to my AbstractFilterableTableColumn.

```
    private void setHeaderNodesEventHandler() {
        for (final Node headerNode : lookupAll(".column-header")) {
            final AbstractFilterableTableColumn<E, ?> column = (AbstractFilterableTableColumn<E, ?>) headerNode.getParent();
            column.setHeaderNodeEventHandler(headerNode);
        }
    }
```

Do you have any ideas to get the headerNodes and their respective table column without trusting the ordering?

So if anyone has a solution for my problem.. i would really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1):

When you create your columns, use a `Label` as a graphic instead of setting the text. Then you can register the mouse listener you need with the `Label`. I haven't tested this, but something along the following lines should work:

```
TableColumn<S, T> column = new TableColumn<S, T>();
Label columnHeader = new Label("Column Name");
column.setGraphic(columnHeader);

// note you can pass your TableColumn to the setHeaderNodeEventHandler(...)
// method too, so you can access the actual column represented if you need
setHeaderNodeEventHandler(columnHeader);
```

Comment: setContentDisplay() is undefined for `TableColumn`, how should this then be done?

Comment: Updated (and simplified). Not sure what I was thinking back when I posted that - I guess I was trying to protect the code against `column.setText(...)` calls. But yes, there is no `contentDisplay` for a `TableColumn` (even though it really seems it should be a `Labeled`).